# Reading leaf nodes from a adjacency model list using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I've a adjacency model list to store a hierarchy as below. The table structure is similar to employees table in Nothwind database. Example given below.

- Employee Id 1 Reports to Employee Id 2
- Employee Id 3 Reports to Employee Id 2
- Employee Id 4 Reports to Employee Id 2
- Employee Id 5 Reports to Employee Id 3
- Employee Id 6 Reports to Employee Id 4
- Employee Id 7 Reports to Employee Id 5
- Employee Id 8 Reports to Employee Id 7.

I want to know the list of leaf node employees, that is employees who are not "Boss" to any other employees. In the above example they are  1, 8 and 6. I tried to write a LINQ extension to get all leaf nodes as given below.

```
        public static IEnumerable<TEntity> SelectDeep<TEntity, TProperty>(
                         this IEnumerable<TEntity> allItems,
                         Func<TEntity, TProperty> idProperty,
                         Func<TEntity, TProperty> parentIdProperty,
                         object rootItemId)
        {
            IEnumerable<TEntity> leve11Data = LevelDeep(allItems, default(TEntity), idProperty, parentIdProperty, rootItemId);
            IEnumerable<TProperty> leafOnly = leve11Data.Select(i => idProperty(i)).Except(leve11Data.Select(i => parentIdProperty(i)));
            IEnumerable<TEntity> childItemsOnly = allItems.Where(i => leafOnly.Contains(idProperty(i)));
            return childItemsOnly;
        }


      public static IEnumerable<TEntity> LevelDeep<TEntity, TProperty>(this IEnumerable<TEntity>allItems,
                    TEntity parentItem,
                    Func<TEntity, TProperty> idProperty,
                    Func<TEntity, TProperty> parentIdProperty,
                    object rootItemId)
        {
            IEnumerable<TEntity> childs;
            if (rootItemId != null)
            {
                childs = allItems.Where(i => parentIdProperty(i).Equals(rootItemId));
            }
            else
            {
                if (parentItem == null)
                {
                    childs = allItems.Where(i => parentIdProperty(i).Equals(default(TProperty)));
                }
                else
                {
                    childs = allItems.Where(i => parentIdProperty(i).Equals(idProperty(parentItem)));
                }
            }
            if (childs.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (TEntity item in childs)
                {
                    yield return item;
                    foreach (TEntity subItem in LevelDeep(allItems, item, idProperty, parentIdProperty, null))
                    {
                        yield return subItem;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And i call it using :

```
   (from listEntry in myList.SelectDeep(e => e.child_part_id, e => e.parent_part_id, 100).ToList()
```

But unfortunately my extension method goes to infinte loop and I am not able to figure out why..
Can somebody please help..

Comment: Why do you have both item and rootItemId in your LevelDeep? Shouldn't that be basically the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are forgetting the `rootItemId` parameter in your recursive call. Try changing it to something like :

```
            foreach (TEntity item in childs)
            {
                yield return item;
                object itemId = idProperty(item);
                foreach (TEntity subItem in LevelDeep(allItems, item, idProperty, parentIdProperty, itemId))
                {
                    yield return subItem;
                }
            }
```

You should actually change the `object` type of all the IDs to `TProperty` type, just to make sure.

Comment: My LevelDeep() logic is based on the idea that in the first call, we will have Id of the room item, but from the next call onwards we will have the parent object in hand. Still I got no clue on why my call goes infinite.:( . I guess I have some misunderstanding on using the "yield", but could not reach any solution yet...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved!.

Problem: It was not actually infinite loop. It happened as SelectDeep() calls LevelDeep() and then it manipulates the results from LevelDeep(), using the variable level1Data. As the variable level1Data does not really evaluate the expression, whenever I tried to access the level1Data, LevelDeep() was getting executed again and again. From the logs I misunderstood as infinite recursion.

Solution : Wrote another extension method FindLeafOnly() as

```
public static IEnumerable<TEntity> FindLeafOnly<TEntity, TProperty>(
                           this IEnumerable<TEntity> leve11Data,
                           Func<TEntity, TProperty> idProperty,
                           Func<TEntity, TProperty> parentIdProperty)
            {   
                IEnumerable<TProperty> allChild = leve11Data.Select(i => idProperty(i));
                IEnumerable<TProperty> allParent = leve11Data.Select(i => parentIdProperty(i));
                IEnumerable<TProperty> leafOnly = allChild.Except(allParent);
                IEnumerable<TEntity> childItemsOnly = leve11Data.Where(i => leafOnly.Contains(idProperty(i)));
                return childItemsOnly;
            }
```

and finally the key to avoid repeated expression evaluation is to call ToList() after SelectDeep() before calling FindLeafOnly(). So the calling code comes like

```
   (from listItem in myAdjucencyModelList.SelectDeep(e => e.child_part_id, e => e.parent_part_id, 5412).ToList().FindLeafOnly(e=> e.child_part_id, e => e.parent_part_id).ToList()
```

The ToList() make sure that the first Linq extension is evaluated before calling next one.